# Rails_admin throwing NoMethodError on nested class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have a `User` model that `has_many :jobs`. Everything seems to work correctly, except when I go to edit a `User` record in rails_admin, I get the following error.

`undefined method rails_admin_default_object_label_method' for #<Job:0x00000102f488c0>`

It says the error was raised on line 12 of `bundler/gems/rails_admin-239c4f6bba32/app/views/rails_admin/main/_form_filtering_multiselect.html.erb`

Since the application itself (outside of rails_admin) seems to be working correctly, I'm not really sure where to start looking for what's missing. Any ideas on what could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably just a Rails Admin bug.  In fact, someone else had a similar error 1 day ago:

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/443

and there has been a commit to Rails Admin 20 hours ago to fix it:

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/commit/5d0cc687fe40fb05f306a171b75477a0564ca901

So I would upgrade Rails Admin to the latest revision and see if it works.

If it doesn't, and you really want to get Rails Admin working, you could begin debugging their code, or provide them with an error report detailing your situation.

Comment: You're correct, when I pulled the latest changes from github everything started working just fine. Thanks!